Can we flag a person?
Because everyone can see this post I will refrain from using names. 
It happens from time to time that a particular (often new) user at cogsci asks many badly phrased questions. That is normally not a problem per se, but even after a lot a helpful comments, some don't show the slightest intent of self reflecting. They are incapable or not willing to improve their posts, and sometimes they are even plain ignorant to the border of being rude (e.g. saying that they cannot imagine how the question is not clear, or expecting other's to edit the post so that it is understandable enough for us). 
What happens to these kinds of users? Can we flag them or limit/pause their posts in any way?

In case they get many questions closed they will hit an automated banned from asking ban. Thus the best resolution is to continue flagging/voting to close.

Mods can do some very useful things, up to removing and banning users/IP addresses. Best thing the common peasant can do is flag a good example question for the mods that represents your worries best, link the other questions in the flag and describe your motivations in the flag. Alternatively, you could flag every post, but that means more work for the mods.
